# Variadic template deduction/matching for a closure class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to create sort of a closure callback class and run into some problems with template parameter deduction and matching

(The class works as follows: Upon construction, it will take a member or non-member function as well as a variable (`CAPARGS`) number of arguments into a closure. The closure can then be called with a variable number of arguments (`CALLARGS`), and it will call its callback function with `CAPARGS` and `CALLARGS`.)

- I get compile errors when invoking its constructors (See below under
  "Test code", two errors are marked).
- Compile errors arise in both cases because it can not find a matching constructor.
- I marked the constructors which SHOULD be taken at each error under "Class code", and I give the error (reason for not matching) given for THAT constructor right below here.

ERROR 1:

> candidate template ignored: could not match 'function' against 'void (*)(int)'

ERROR 2:

> note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction

Class code:

```
template <class... CALLARGS>
class Closure{

    public:

        // Constructor intended for use at ERROR 1
        template <class OBJ, class... CAPARGS>
        Closure(OBJ* obj, void (OBJ::*fct)(CAPARGS..., CALLARGS...), CAPARGS... capArgs){
            callback =
                [=] (CALLARGS... callArgs) -> void{
                    (obj->*fct)(capArgs..., callArgs...);
                };
        }

        // Constructor intended for use at ERROR 1
        template <class... CAPARGS>
        Closure(std::function<void(CAPARGS..., CALLARGS...)>, CAPARGS... capArgs){
            callback =
                [=] (CALLARGS... callArgs) -> void{
                    fct(capArgs..., callArgs...);
                };
        }

        void operator () (CALLARGS... callArgs){
            callback(callArgs...);
        }

    private:
        std::function<void(CALLARGS...)> callback;

};
```

Test code:

```
class A{
    public:
        virtual void fct(int a){
            ...
        }
};


void plusF(int a){
    ...
}

int main(void) {

    A a;

    Closure<int> callF(plusF); // **ERROR 1 from here**
    Closure<int> callA(&a, &A::fct); // **ERROR 2 from here**

    callF(1);
    callA(2);

}
```

I'm aware that maybe I'm doing stuff which exceeds my skills. But can I somehow fix this?

(Btw, side question: Is it reasonable to call this class Closure, or does such a construct have a different name?)

Comment: Note that `std::bind` may help.

Comment: You can for example store the arguments in an std::tuple and then you can call the function with std::apply if you have a modern compiler... it's a little bit different than your solution

Comment: `CAPARGS` can't be deduced from anything that is not a `std::function`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: No, it's meant like in the code. The function needs to be able to take `CAPARGS` as well as `CALLARGS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your variadic template are non deductible (or create conflict), you may do instead:

```
template <class... CALLARGS>
class Closure{
public:

    template <class OBJ, typename M, class... CAPARGS>
    Closure(OBJ* obj, M (OBJ::*fct), CAPARGS... capArgs){
        callback =
            [=] (CALLARGS... callArgs) -> void{
                (obj->*fct)(capArgs..., callArgs...);
            };
    }

    template <typename F, class... CAPARGS>
    Closure(F fct, CAPARGS... capArgs){
        callback =
            [=] (CALLARGS... callArgs) -> void{
                fct(capArgs..., callArgs...);
            };
    }
    void operator () (CALLARGS... callArgs){
        callback(callArgs...);
    }
private:
    std::function<void(CALLARGS...)> callback;
};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/11Twfn)

`std::bind` may be a simpler alternative:

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
A a;

auto callF = std::bind(plusF, _1);
auto callA = std::bind(&A::fct, &a, _1);

callF(1);
callA(2);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ec02zQ)

Comment: Thanks, that helps. But it's some kind of magic for me... Could you recommend a good starting point (link, search words, book) for learning more about this?

Comment: That PMF should really be reduced to a simple pointer to member (a `F O::*`); as it is it doesn't handle `const` member functions etc. Also, the class type of the PMF should be allowed to be different from `OBJ`, as otherwise it will break with inherited members.